# Plot many functions in single figure in Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, plot, figure

In Matlab I have data in the form:

```
k1=[1 2 3 ...]
f1=[34 23 12 ...]
k2=[ ... ]
f2=[ ... ]
k3=
f3=
...
```

To plot k1(f1) I use

```
plot (k1,f1)
```

How can I simply plot all k#(f#) on one figure without calling `plot` every time?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write multiple variables use [plot](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) in order to get multiple variables on the same figure follow the pattern bellow..

```
k1=[1 2 3 ...]
f1=[34 23 12 ...]
k2=[ ... ]
f2=[ ... ]
k3=
f3=

figure
plot (k1,f1,k2,f2,k3,f3)
```

**EDIT 1:**
since your data is in vector form as shown in your question then concatenating them into groups of `k` and `f` will allow you to iterate through a loop and match the columns you want from each array with each other..

I put the source of this info as a link from youtube in the comments below then decided to add it here as wellfor convenience.

```
f1 = [34 23 12];
f2 = [5 6 7];
f3 = [18 22 34];

k1 = [1 2 3];
k2 = [3 5 6];
k3 = [8 3 2];

k = cat(1, k1, k2, k3);
f = cat(1, f1, f2, f3);

[~, col] = size(k);

hold on;

for kk = 1 : col

    plot(k(:,kk), f(:,kk))

end
```

[image: results of code from EDIT1]

Comment: Is there any way I can put numbering in the loop, something like `for i=1:N` where i is the index for k and f? I have pretty long list of k,f.